# Concatenar varias filas en una sola mysql

Tags: php, mysql

La verdad no se si se podrá, espero respuestas

Unir filas de acuerdo al nombre y nombreu, haciendo la operación:
(peso*nota)/100 al final sumar cada resultado y ponerlo en una sola fila, quedando algo así:

```
nombre            nota
POO II            14.2
POO               14.4
```

Y si habría mas unidades algo así:

```
nombre            nota1       nota2     nota3 
POO II            14.2
POO               14.4

select asignatura.nombre,unidad.nombreu,valoracion.nombrev,valoracion.peso,nota.nota 
from nota 
INNER JOIN asignatura on asignatura.codasig=nota.asignatura 
INNER JOIN unidad on unidad.id=nota.unidad 
INNER JOIN valoracion on valoracion.id=nota.valoracion 
where nota.estudiante='15104055' LIMIT 0, 30 ;


nombre  nombreu         nombrev       peso    nota
POO II  Primera Unidad  Examen         40     10
POO II  Primera Unidad  Practica       40     18
POO II  Primera Unidad  Actitudinal    20     15
POO     Primera Unidad  Examen         30     18
POO     Primera Unidad  Practica       50     10
POO     Primera Unidad  Actitudinal    20     20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer no es posible ya que quieres listar atributos de una misma columna como múltiples columnas independientes.
Por lo que se me ocurren dos alternativas para ofrecerte.

1)- Podrías agrupar por nombre y tener las sumas de las notas:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nombre, " ", nombreu) as nombre, SUM(peso*nota/100) as nota
FROM nota 
INNER JOIN asignatura on asignatura.codasig=nota.asignatura 
INNER JOIN unidad on unidad.id=nota.unidad 
INNER JOIN valoracion on valoracion.id=nota.valoracion 
WHERE nota.estudiante='15104055'
GROUP BY nombre
LIMIT 0, 30 ;
```

2)- Obtenes todos los registros con sus notas aparte:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nombre, " ", nombreu) as nombre, peso*nota/100 as nota
    FROM nota 
    INNER JOIN asignatura on asignatura.codasig=nota.asignatura 
    INNER JOIN unidad on unidad.id=nota.unidad 
    INNER JOIN valoracion on valoracion.id=nota.valoracion 
    WHERE nota.estudiante='15104055'
    LIMIT 0, 30 ;
```

Y después con lógica de un lenguaje de programación como PHP haces una tabla con los atributos.

Por favor, notar que es figurativo, quizás tengas que adaptar los nombres de las tablas o atributos, pero lo dejo a modo de ejemplo para que puedas observar el modo de uso del `GROUP BY` y el `CONCAT()` que te van a ser útiles para lo que estás necesitando.

Saludos!

Comment: `nombre                         nota
POO Primera Unidad 14.4000
POO II Primera Unidad 14.2000`

ahora digamos que tengo

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario, hubo algún problema o fue lo que esperabas?

Comment: digamos que tengo en nombre: POO Primera unidad esto en una fila y en otra tengo POO Segunda unidad como uno las notas para que se vean algo como :POO Nota1 Nota2 Nota3 Nota4

Comment: Ahí te entendí mejor, ahí edité mi respuesta de acuerdo al comentario :)

Answer (score 0):

intenta algo como esto:

```
    select n.nombre,
    SUM(case WHEN n.nombrev='Examen' then (n.peso*n.nota/100)END) as nota1,
    SUM(case WHEN n.nombrev='Practica' then (n.peso*n.nota/100)  END) as nota2,
    SUM(case WHEN n.nombrev='Actitudinal' then (n.peso*n.nota/100) END) as nota3
    from nota n
    INNER JOIN asignatura a on a.codasig=n.asignatura 
    INNER JOIN unidad u on u.id=n.unidad 
    INNER JOIN valoracion v on v.id=n.valoracion 
    where n.estudiante='15104055' 
    group by n.estudiante,n.nombre,u.nombreu
    LIMIT 0, 30 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Observa este esquema, el podría ser mejorable:

Puedes agregar las sumas que quieras, y probar las consultas en este [sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dbc1/10).

Tendrás una línea por asignatura y una columna con **todas las notas de todas las unidades de un estudiante separadas por un carácter (| en este caso)** si quieres dividir cada nota en otras columnas lo puedes hacer por programación, haciendo split sobre la columna notas. La ventaja (entre otras) es que, si no sabes cuántas notas podría tener un estudiante, lo mejor es tener una sola columna donde recibes todas las notas y luego divides las mismas como quieras, sabiendo que hay un '|' entre cada una.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dbc1/10)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE estudiantes
    (`id_estudiante` int, `estudiante` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO estudiantes
    (`id_estudiante`, `estudiante` )
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro'),
    (2, 'Santiago'),
    (3, 'Juan')
;


CREATE TABLE asignaturas
    (`id_asignatura` int, `asignatura` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO asignaturas
    (`id_asignatura`, `asignatura`)
VALUES
    (1, 'POO'),
    (2, 'POO II'),
    (3, 'Java')
;

CREATE TABLE unidades
    (`id_unidad` int, `unidad` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO unidades
    (`id_unidad`, `unidad`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Primera Unidad'),
    (2, 'Segunda Unidad'),
    (3, 'Tercera Unidad')
;


CREATE TABLE valoraciones
    (`id_valoracion` int, `valoracion` varchar(70), `peso` int)
;

INSERT INTO valoraciones
    (`id_valoracion`, `valoracion`, `peso` )
VALUES
    (1, 'Examen',40),
    (2, 'Práctica',40),
    (3, 'Actitudinal',20)
;


CREATE TABLE notas
    (`id` int, `id_estudiante` int, `id_asignatura` int, `id_unidad` int, `id_valoracion` int, `nota` float)
;

INSERT INTO notas
    (`id`, `id_estudiante`, `id_asignatura`, `id_unidad`, `id_valoracion`, `nota`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14.2),
    (2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 14.4),
    (3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 13.4),
    (4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 13.9),
    (5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 10.2),
    (6, 1, 2, 2, 2, 18.4)


;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  e.estudiante, a.asignatura, 
  v.valoracion, v.peso
  ,
  GROUP_CONCAT(n.nota SEPARATOR '|') AS nota
  FROM estudiantes e 
  JOIN notas n ON e.id_estudiante=n.id_estudiante
  JOIN asignaturas a ON n.id_asignatura=a.id_asignatura
  JOIN unidades u ON n.id_unidad=u.id_unidad
  JOIN valoraciones v ON v.id_valoracion=n.id_valoracion
  WHERE e.id_estudiante=1
  GROUP BY e.id_estudiante, a.id_asignatura
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dbc1/10/0)**:

> ```
> | estudiante | asignatura | valoracion | peso |      nota |
> |------------|------------|------------|------|-----------|
> |      Pedro |        POO |     Examen |   40 | 10.2|14.2 |
> |      Pedro |     POO II |   Práctica |   40 | 14.4|18.4 |
> ```